# "Has anyone forwarded this to you too?" vs. "Have you too been forwarded this by someone?"

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

Is "Has anyone forwarded this to you too?" a grammatically correct question, or should I have asked "Have you too been forwarded this by someone?"

Comment: Other than first construction being active and the latter passive plus, mind, very formal in modern English, I don't see much difference.

Comment: Second sentence seems ambiguous about what has been forwarded. The first sentence sounds more natural.

Comment: Having non-native speakers of English in my circle of friends, the second sentence sounds like a literal translation. Generally, people learning a foreign language do speak more formally. The first sentence, in my opinion is no less formal, since it is correct.

Comment: Has anyone else sent you this?

Answer (score 0):

Both are grammatically correct, but unless there's an overriding reason to use passive voice, active voice should be used.

Given that, the better choice would be to use **"Has anyone forwarded this to you, too?"**

Comment: I agree with Otomatonium, except that I see no need for the comma between "you" and "too" at the end of the sentence.